# How to determine which process sends UDP packets periodically to an IP address?

Tags: linux, networking, udp

I tried looping with `netstat` and  but the packets are small and not frequent so do not get caught (can still see them with `tcpdump`). Need to know which process sends those packets.

Comment: Have you tired iptables --log-uid option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `tcpdump` for the source port number of the packets.  Then run

```
sudo netstat -a -u -n --program
```

Look for the `PID/Program name` matching the source port number.

This assumes that the sending process is leaving its socket open between sends, which is what any normal program would do.  If you are dealing a program that is deliberately trying to hide itself, that's whole different story.

Answer (score -1):

I guess it should be possible with [`QUEUE`](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/packet-filtering-HOWTO-7.html#ss7.4) target in `iptables`. But you'd need to write an userspace application to "check" those packets (and this appication could help you to know which process sends those packets). Sorry, I haven't got more details.